# How to secrete more pheromones while in the presence of the opposite sex?

Tags: medical-myths, sociosexual-behavior, pheromones, sudoriferous-sweat-glands

**How to secrete more pheromones while in the presence of the opposite sex?**

I know that those of us who have gone through puberty secret a sexual pheromone that supposedly "attracts" the other sex. I'm not sure how true that is in this day and age in the human world, but if it is, is there a way to secrete more pheromones while in the presence of the opposite sex? Or does that just mean, I'd have to sweat profusely, in which case, that wouldn't be that attractive. I know that there are products out there that claim to be pheromone perfumes or whatever, but aren't pheromones unique to each person? So that seem like it would be bunk.

Is it true that men typically find women more attractive when they are ovulating because of their pheromones?

Comment: You mis-understand pheromones.

Comment: @JJosaur, I meant it facetiously, but please do elaborate it in an answer. I couldn't tag "medical myths" because there were already  tags.

Comment: You're asking three questions. Asking one question at a time is best for several reasons. ===> [How do I ask a good question?](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)